# ORDER BY Impacting the performance of sql query

Tags: sql-server

The below query is taking long time if done with `ORDER BY` Clause.

```
select a.* 
  from table_a a
    left join table_b b on a.colid = b.colid 
  where (
        a.colid = 0 
    or a.colid = b.colid
    )
  order by a.colid2, a.colid3 asc
```

Primary Key Clustered Index For `Table_A` is `(colid2,colid3)`

Non Clustered Index For `Table_A` is `(colid)`

Non Clustered Index For `Table_B` is `(colid)`

Execution time with `ORDER BY` is taking 13 sec whereas without `ORDER BY` is taking  1 sec.

Comment: well this is normal, ordering takes time...

Comment: Yep, order by is expensive. What exactly is your question though?

Comment: Yep.  In a scalable app, one technique is to sort nothing in the database, and let the middle-ware machines do the sorting.  Aka, something like "let the C# code do the sorting".

Comment: How many rows are you returning? 13 seconds seems like it is a little long depending on how many rows you are looking at. How many rows are in each table? How many rows are in your result set?

Comment: Both the tables contain more than 100 thousand records, and i cannot do in C# because it is for implementing restart key functionality to identify the records which are already treated, in case the job end abruptly.

Comment: Are you SEEING the INITIAL results in one second, but the actual completion takes several seconds?

Comment: You might try adding a nonclustered index on those columns, that would help with sorting time

Comment: YES I am seeing initial results in one second . I have added the  non clusured indexes on these columns still the result is same

Comment: Actually i am looking for suggestion on adding non clustered indexes to reduce sorting time. How to identify the columns to be used for creation of non clustured index

Comment: How is your query even working? The aliases have not been specified.

Comment: i cannot post the actual query...so posted a similar query fixed the issue with aliases

Answer (score 1):

Clauses like GROUP BY, ORDER BY, LIKE ,DISTINCT are relatively more time consuming. If you are using them try evaluating it while scripting. Do not use sub-queries. Do not compute inside your query, evaluate it earlier if possible.

Sensible indexing + relevant caching + partitioning(if required) should solve your problem.

I believe you should index the colid2 .

Comment: No there are Clauses like GROUP BY, ORDER BY, LIKE ,DISTINCT . ONLY LEFT JOIN Where clause

Comment: @phanish: I know. Its a generic suggestion. I have mentioned that you should index the colid2. But don't expect very high performance. Because you are already ordering it

Comment: TOP Clause is used for specifying the transaction size which is degrading the performance as well

Comment: @phanish:  I second you

Answer (score 0):

Depending on which version of SQL Server you are using, locking hints might help, try:

```
select a.* 
from table_a a with (nolock)
left join table_b b with (nolock)
on a.colid = b.colid 
where a.colid = 0 
or a.colid = b.colid
order by a.colid2,
    a.colid3 asc
```

If that doesn't help, try reducing the query to simple joins like so:

```
--this is equivalent to your original query 
select *
from (
    select *
    from table_a
    where colid = 0
    union
    select a.*
    from table_a as a
    inner join table_b as b
    on b.colid = a.colid
    ) as tbl
order by colid2,
    colid3
```

Comment: Thanks for suggesting. I got enhanced performance by doing the following changes                                                                                                                                           1. create temp table for table_a 2. create clustured index for temp table 3. insert into temp table with the join clause 4.select temp table based on parameters and order by